# "One or more networking protocols are missing in this computer"

Tags: networking, windows-10, remote-desktop

Everytime I try to use remote assitance as a invited person even typing the right password I get the following warning:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/o7D3YST.png]

Sorry for the portuguese. The question's tittle is problem at the pic and the solution's translation is "try execute the repair as admin"

I'm using a Dell inspiron 3442 with windows 10 with all the lastest updates. Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: When you do escalate the repair as an admin does the same error message appear?  Have you run both SFC and DISM to eliminate any possible system integrity issues from the picture?  Have you install the "Windows 10 1511" update yet?  If you are not running Version 1511 of Windows 10 indicate what build of Windows 10 you are using in the question itself.

Comment: Yes. I had run both SFC and DISM and they detected nothing. And yes, my version is 1511

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing the same issue but was able to resolve it by switching off my WiFi, then disabling the WiFi network adapter (sounds redundant yes but I was trying everything, lol), after re-enabling the adapter and turning back on my WiFi I was once again connected. Hope this helps. *Posted by anonymous.*